# Install OpenMPI from repository with GCC instead of Intel

Tags: apt, software-installation, gcc, mpi

I would like to install openmpi from repository and need to use it with GCC. The problem is I have installed intel libraries too and it causes problems like this:

```
mpicc.openmpi --version
mpicc.openmpi: error while loading shared libraries: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Version of my GCC is:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
```

I'm trying to install openmpi with following command:

```
sudo aptitude install  openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev
```

So, how can I install OpenMPI from repositories in the way which would ignore intel libraries and use only GCC?

---

#### EDIT

```
which mpicc.openmpi
/usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi

ldd $(which mpicc.openmpi)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd6fc0000)
libopen-pal.so.13 => /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.13 (0x00007f9b0c8d0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9b0c6b3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9b0c2e9000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9b0bfe0000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9b0bddc000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9b0bbd3000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f9b0b9d0000)
libimf.so => not found
libsvml.so => not found
libirng.so => not found
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9b0b7b9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056030ed59000)
libintlc.so.5 => not found
```

I've installed intel package [Intel® Parallel Studio XE | Intel® Software](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-parallel-studio-xe) manually (i.e., ./install_gui.sh).

---

#### EDIT 2

I tried to reinstall OpenMPI with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev
```

and with

```
sudo apt-get purge openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev
```

but none of them had the desired effect, library still links
against intel libraries.

Intel libraries are located in `/opt/intel`.

---

#### EDIT 3

```
ls -l /usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi /usr/bin/opal_wrapper; apt-cache policy openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    12 Feb 25  2016 /usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi -> opal_wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18928 Feb 25  2016 /usr/bin/opal_wrapper


apt-cache policy openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev
openmpi-bin:
  Installed: 1.10.2-8ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.10.2-8ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libopenmpi-dev:
  Installed: 1.10.2-8ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.10.2-8ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add which intel libs did you install and how did you install them? Also the output of `which mpicc.openmpi; ldd $(which mpicc.openmpi)`

Comment: @user.dz I've added info into my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As it seems, the Intel `mpicc.openmpi` overwrote the official one from repository or one of its linked libraries.

  Here is my output of a official install from repository:

  ```
    ~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi
    libopenmpi-dev: /usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi

    ~$ ldd /usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd785f4000)
        libopen-pal.so.13 => /usr/lib/libopen-pal.so.13 (0x00007ff1d848d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff1d8270000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff1d7ea6000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff1d7ca2000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff1d7a9a000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ff1d7896000)
        libhwloc.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.5 (0x00007ff1d765c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056499326f000)
        libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007ff1d7450000)
        libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007ff1d7246000)
  ```

  It does not relay on those missing libraries.
- To fix it you can reinstall libopenmpi:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev
  ```
- Also notice `/usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.13`. It's in `/usr/local/lib/` folder so it has higher priority then official one in `/usr/lib/`, compatibility may be broken.

  Check for all sub-versions using

  ```
    ls -l /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.13*
  ```

  then rename them, example

  ```
    sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.13 /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.13.backup
  ```

Comment: I added more details into my question.

Comment: @AlexandrosMarkopoulos, could you add output of `ls -l /usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi /usr/bin/opal_wrapper; apt-cache policy openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev`

Comment: I added other details into my question.

Comment: @AlexandrosMarkopoulos, it could due to this library `/usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.13`, check for all versions  `ls -l /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.13*` then rename them example `sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.13 /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.13.backup`

Comment: Great! Finally, it works. Could you, please, add this info to your answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: @AlexandrosMarkopoulos, nice, i've updated it.